# Global variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, controller, var

i'm looking for a way to use a global varable in a angularjs function.

I found this way, to use the global var as a angular var:

```
var AppSettings = angular.module('settingsApp', []);
AppSettings.controller('settingsCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {

   $scope.sessionUID = $window.sessionUID;

 /** function to update user details after edit from list of user php **/
    $scope.changefunction = function() {
                    alert("perfect");
    };

}]);
var MyApp = angular.module('biqs_settings_app', ['settingsApp']);
```

But now I cant run the "changefunction".

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12346)
    at callback (angular.js:21435)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14401)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14500)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21440)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3014)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does the console give any errors?

Comment: To use golbal var generally is not a good idea. Why you want use a global var? Can you explain better please?

Comment: I'm checking the sessionvariable as a var to let the logged in user change his password.

Comment: error says that you are messing on `HTML`, could you show a HTML?

Comment: Looks like i used the same name for my form and function. Thats why. But now i'm getting "ReferenceError: $http is not defined" which i use in my function.

Answer (score 0):

Everything will work, if you properly use the `settingsCtrl` controller in your HTML:

```
<div ng-app="biqs_settings_app" ng-controller="settingsCtrl">
    <button ng-click="changefunction()">Test</button>
</div>
```